# Make Firefox left-click open in current tab, and middle-click open in new tab

Tags: firefox, javascript

I'm sick of the inconsistent behavior of clicking on links in Firefox.  I want control of where they open up.  If I'm done with a page and want to replace it with the link I am clicking, I left-click.  If there are things I want to look at in the future, but I'm not done with this page yet, I'll middle-click.  This normally works, but there are exceptions.

- If the website designer uses `target="_blank"`, my left-click is overridden and the link opens in a new tab/window.
- If the links are javascript, a middle-click rarely works.  I get an *(Untitled)* tab with some javascript as the URL.
- etc.

How do I fix these things and get consistent clicking on links?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) primarily for its ability to control how things are opened, but it's also got a ton of other features.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

1. Type in `about:config` in the address bar and press *enter*.
2. Search for `browser.link`
3. Set `browser.link.open_newwindow` to **1** instead of 3.